# Accidental modified SELinux context on root account to staff_u

Tags: selinux

I logged in as a normal account(test) on my CentOS 6.5 VM and `sudo su - root` and run `usermod -Z staff_u test`

but looks like it changed my root account to staff_u as well, now I am stuck, could not change it back.

```
bash-4.1# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
bash-4.1# id -Z
staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
bash-4.1# bash
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
bash-4.1# setenforce 0
setenforce:  setenforce() failed
bash-4.1# sudo setenforce 0
setenforce:  setenforce() failed
bash-4.1# cd .ssh
bash: cd: .ssh: Permission denied
bash-4.1# cd 
bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
bash-4.1# usermod -Z unconfined_u root
usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
bash-4.1# cat /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
bash-4.1#
```

Direct root login disabled, but don't think it will help anyway, any idea ? It is just a VM, does not really matter but would like to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Tried following and it fixed it, actually easier than I thought

- Reboot into single user mode
- Changed selinux=permissive in /etc/selinux/config file
- Reset root password as well since I don't remember it
- Reboot
- Login as test(staff_u) and run `sudo semanage login -a -s unconfined_u root`
- Change selinux back to enforcing in /etc/selinux/config file
- Reboot

Problem fixed.